# Is there a way to access the worms across the dig site on Ginger Island?

Tags: stardew-valley

Ever since I've had access to Ginger Island, there are these worms in the ground I've been wanting to dig up but I have not figured out how to get across. Is there a path to get to this part of the map or is this likely a bug?

(See the worms at the very bottom left under the palm tree)

[image: Wanted worms at bottom left]

Comment: Use a mod that lets you ignore collision and noclip your way over there?

Comment: I’d have to look into that! Haven’t used mods before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inaccessible forage items and dig sites can appear throughout the game, not just on Ginger Island. Nothing to do when that happens, other than sigh and wait enough days for them to disappear.

Comment: that is helpful. Although these worms are haunting me! It’s been days 